# WAMP Not working Correctly

Tags: wamp

First time using WAMP, as I really want something to do. So basically, when I go to http://localhost/, Firefox says it's unable to connect. And, even if it did work, where would I put the files to display my website?

Comment: This is more something for superuser

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure all the services are running properly ? the icon in the bottom right should be white, if its not then click on it and click on the "start all services".

You place your files in the www folder in the install directory of wamp (usually C:/Program Files/wamp/www/ )

Ikke meant the question should be on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

first of all stop these applications skype,sql server, IIS Server, then it will work.
you can stop sql server from SQL Server 2014 Configuration manager and IIS Server from Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you installed Wampserver correct.

If `http://localhost/` doesn't work.
Try browse to `127.0.0.1` in your browser.

Make sure your Wampserver icon is Green.

- Red = Offline/major error
- Orange = not all services are started. Won't work.
- Green = You're allright! I'm working